# closing python command subprocesses

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I want to continue with commands after closing subprocess. I have following code but `fsutil` is not executed. how can I do it?

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

os.system('mkdir c:\\temp\\vhd')
p = Popen( ["diskpart"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE )
p.stdin.write("create vdisk file=c:\\temp\\vhd\\test.vhd maximum=2000 type=expandable\n")
p.stdin.write("attach vdisk\n")
p.stdin.write("create partition primary size=10\n")
p.stdin.write("format fs=ntfs quick\n")
p.stdin.write("assign letter=r\n")
p.stdin.write("exit\n")
p.stdout.close
os.system('fsutil file createnew r:\dummy.txt 6553600') #this doesn´t get executed
```

Comment: Please don't use `os.system()` anymore. It is very old fashioned, proposed deprecated for a long time.

Comment: how do you suggest if not to include the fsutil line on my code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `p.stdout.close()`? I think you are missing some parentheses.

Comment: Actually, aren't you missing a `p.communicate()` after `p.stdin.write("exit\n")`?

Comment: with the () added got same result. p.communicate()? how would that be ?

Answer (score 2):

At the least, I think you need to change your code to look like this:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

os.system('mkdir c:\\temp\\vhd')
p = Popen(["diskpart"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("create vdisk file=c:\\temp\\vhd\\test.vhd maximum=2000 type=expandable\n")
p.stdin.write("attach vdisk\n")
p.stdin.write("create partition primary size=10\n")
p.stdin.write("format fs=ntfs quick\n")
p.stdin.write("assign letter=r\n")
p.stdin.write("exit\n")
results, errors = p.communicate()
os.system('fsutil file createnew r:\dummy.txt 6553600')
```

From the [documentation for `Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

You could replace the `p.communicate()` with `p.wait()`, but there is this warning in the [documentation for `Popen.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)

> **Warning** This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.